# Need help understanding Chapter 2 of Joseph J. Rotman's: An Introduction to Theory of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to self learn Group Theory and I'm starting with this book. On page 20, start of Chapter 2, the book immediately introduces a subgroup as:

> **Definition.** A nonempty subset of S of a group G is a  **subgroup** of G if $s \in G$ implies $s^{-1} \in G$ and $s,t \in G$ imply $st \in G$.

On the same page, for the proof of Theorem 2.1: Every subgroup is a group in its own right, the book starts with:

> The hypothesis '$s,t \in S$ imply $st \in S$' shows that $S$...

Is the former line just a typo, and if so, is it a known typo? Or am I missing something? I always thought a subgroup was just a subset that satisfied the four group laws, am I mistaken?

I can post photos of my textbook if needed, I do not have an online copy, only a hard cover copy.

Comment: In the definition of "subgroup" that you quoted, the last four occurrences of $G$ should be $S$. Yes, that's a typo (or four typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the former line just a typo, and if so, is it a known typo? Or am I missing something?

The use of $G$ should be $S$. Yes, it is known.

> I always thought a subgroup was just a subset that satisfied the four group laws, am I mistaken?

There are multiple ways for a subset of a group to be a subgroup. Consider, for example,

> **Theorem (One-step Subgroup Test):** Suppose $S$ is a nonempty subset of a group $G$. Then TFAE:
>
> - $a,b\in S$ implies $ab^{-1}\in S$.
> - $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. I've accepted the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, @person.